# How to convert HTML request to JSON in python

Tags: python, html, json, request, localhost

I've been working with the HTML requests system for a while and facing issues regards on HTML requests and JSON requests. I want to convert `name=dev&role=director` to

```
{
  'name': 'dev',
  'role': 'director'
}
```

Code:

```
def do_POST(self):
       self.send_response(200)
       self.send_header('Content-Type', "application/json")
       self.end_headers
       content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
       post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len,)
       posttype = str(post_body, 'utf-8')
       print(posttype)
```

Request Code:

```
header = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
}

content ={
    'name': 'dev',
     'role': 'director'
}
r = requests.post(
    "http://localhost:8080/",
    headers=header,
    data= content
)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You are trying to convert this to a dictionary? What did you get before?

Comment: This `name=dev&role=director`

Comment: Is it okay for you to change this after you get it? Or do you want to get the changed version?

Comment: @Batselot Thanks for the reply. What I want to do is convert this request to JSON format. I don't know how to do that. Can you please help me with this.